# How do we implement SAF in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on a project where i need to copy, delete files from a specific folder (Android/Media). But as per android SAF guidelines we need to prompt user so they can select the folder and allow to use it (e.g. USE THIS FOLDER). I want you help to know that how do we actually check if SAF is granted and if its granted how do we store the granted folder and further use it.

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    PermissionHandler {
        MediaScreen()
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
fun PermissionHandler(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val permissionsList = listOf(
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    )
    val uri = remember {
        mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null)
    }
    val permission = rememberMultiplePermissionsState(permissions = permissionsList)
    val safLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree()){ Uri ->

    }
    if (permission.allPermissionsGranted) {
        if (uri.value == null){
            Button(onClick = { safLauncher.launch(Uri.parse("emulated/0/android/media")) }) {
                Text(text = "Please Select folder")
            }
        } else {
            content()
        }
} else {
    AccessInfo(
        accessModel = permissions[0],
        isPopupEnabled = false,
        onDetailLinkClick = { /*TODO*/ },
        onPopUpButtonClick = { /*TODO*/ },
        onAllowButtonClick = { permission.launchMultiplePermissionRequest() })
}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use ```Whatsapp``` status path using SAF?

Comment: Yes @ChiragThummar

Comment: Okay I'll give you a example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code. There is a lot of things need after this you can play around and get it.

First of need custom contract for the activityResultLauncher so here I have made

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Environment
import android.os.Parcelable
import android.os.storage.StorageManager
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import com.md.whatsapppath.Constants.whatsappUriForMatching


class WhatsappDocumentContract : ActivityResultContract<Uri?, Uri?>() {

    private fun getRootFolderPath(): String {
        return "Android%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses"
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Uri?): Intent {
        val intent: Intent
        val storageManager = context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
        val yourFolderPath: String = getRootFolderPath()

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            intent = storageManager.primaryStorageVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()
            val replace =
                (intent.getParcelableExtra(
                    "android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI",
                    Parcelable::class.java
                ) as Uri).toString()
                    .replace("/root/", "/document/")
            intent.putExtra(
                "android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI",
                Uri.parse("$replace%3A$yourFolderPath")
            )
            whatsappUriForMatching = Uri.parse("$replace%3A$yourFolderPath")
        } else {
            //for our case this is useless because for P and Q we are using normal scenario
            intent = Intent("android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE")
            intent.putExtra(
                "android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI",
                Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3A$yourFolderPath")
            )
            whatsappUriForMatching =
                Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3A$yourFolderPath")
        }
        intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true)

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)

        return intent
    }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Uri? {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            return null
        }
        return intent?.data
    }
}
```

Other Required Classes

```
object Constants {
    var whatsappUriForMatching: Uri? = null
}

object StorageUtil {
    fun isWhatsappUriPermissionGranted(mContext: Context): Boolean {
        return mContext.contentResolver.persistedUriPermissions.filter { it.uri.toString() == "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses" }
            .isNotEmpty()
    }
}
```

Use `CustomDocumentContact` for permission and get the permission.

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.compose.rememberLauncherForActivityResult
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun WhatsappPath(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    val context = LocalContext.current

    val whatsappPermissionLauncher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = WhatsappDocumentContract(),
            onResult = { result ->
                if (result != null) {
                    val strResult: String =
                        result.toString().substring(result.toString().lastIndexOf("/"))

                    val actualSelectedUri: String = Constants.whatsappUriForMatching.toString()
                        .substring(Constants.whatsappUriForMatching.toString().lastIndexOf("/"))
                    if (actualSelectedUri == strResult) {
                        val takeFlags =
                            (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
                        context.contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(result, takeFlags)

                        //Permission Granted Save It In SharedPreference
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    } else {
                        //Selected Wrong Locations
                        Toast.makeText(
                            context, "Selected Wrong Whatsapp Locations", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                }
            })


    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(horizontal = 30.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 30.dp)
            .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(45.dp)
            .clickable {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    if (!StorageUtil.isWhatsappUriPermissionGranted(context)) {
                        whatsappPermissionLauncher.launch(null)
                    } else {
                        //Permission Given Do your work
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }

                } else {
                    //Request For Write External Storage Permission
                }
            }
            .background(
                brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                    colors = listOf(
                        Color(0xFFF4CDBC),
                        Color(0xFFCACFF9),
                    )
                )
            ), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            Text("Allow Permission", color = Color.Black)
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tired it in different way here is what i have tried. I want to ask you if my code is correct ? Here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C-COS9w9ZXrKASxV4csmjkNkCynr5X3p/view?usp=drive_link